# Update hidden input value with onclick event from ajax drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I'm working with MachForm and have this hidden field that I've added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="element_273_price" value="">
```

I've integrated an ajax drop down menu that allows for an onclick event to be fired. I'd like the hidden field above to have a value inputted after the onclick event (onclick would tell the hidden field what the item was and price for that item) so that I can then pass it along through the rest of the JavaScript for the updating of the price on screen.

Here's my code for calculating a text box:

```
        $('#main_body li[data-pricefield="text"]').delegate('input.text','keyup mouseout change', function(e) {
        var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
        var element_id = temp[1];
        var ordered = (document.getElementById("element_" + element_id).value);
        var price = $(this).data('pricedef');

        var price_value = price * ordered;
        price_value = parseFloat(price_value);
        if(isNaN(price_value)){
            price_value = 0;
        }

        $("#li_" + element_id).data("pricevalue",price_value);
        calculate_total_payment();
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help if you posted some of your javascript code.

Comment: @Aaron, I have't really tried anything, because I don't know what would work, in order to update that input hidden value. Once I have that value updated, I can calculate from there. I will add my other code up top for calculating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put in your php file:

```
'onlick' => '$("element_'.$yourelementid.'_price").val("'.$data['price'].'");'
```

Then you'll have in your javascript to get the value from this hidden input instead of the data-pricedef attribute of your "Quantity" input.

Correct me if I do not understand your problem. I tried to reply from the code you showed in your video.

Comment: You and I are on the right track. I had this before you responded: 'onclick' => 'document.getElementById(\'element_273_price\').val=\'3.00\'', and even tho it's hard coded - it seems to be doing the trick, console.log seems to show the value being updated. So you are right my friend.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the input to

```
<input type="hidden" id="element_273_price" value="">
```

You should be able to do

```
$("#element_273_price").val(price_value);
```

Comment: here's a good explanation of what I'm attempting to have happen http://screencast.com/t/Bgvnz9Ds63rw